# Python how to use the for loop

Tags: python

I'm just trying to get a better understanding of python so I thought I would use 
stack overflow as a tutorial.
I'm a complete newbie so bear with me, this is a sample code I would like to add a for statement or any loop to make the code try 3 attempts before it exits with
'bugger off'

```
username = input('Login:>>')

user1 = 'jack'
user2 = 'jill'

if username == user1:
   print('access granted')

elif username == user2:
   print('welcome to the system')

else:
   print('access denied')
```

Comment: stackoverflow is not a tutorial. Please do research before posting questions. There are plenty of tutorial sites on the internet. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432

Answer (score 2):

```
user1 = 'jack'
user2 = 'jill'
for i in range(3):

    username = input('Login:>>')

    if username == user1:
        print('access granted')
        break

    elif username == user2:
        print('welcome to the system')
        break

    else:
        print('access denied')
```

In this code, we use a for loop which will run for 3 times.
But if the username which is typed is true, the program exits for loop with `break` command...
We didn't put `break` statement in `else` condition so that user can be able to try the username for 3 times.

**Edit**

After comment of @kindall I need to edit my answer...
When the code above is run, 'access denied' message is shown on screen three times but If you want to show it only one time, you should use this code:

```
user1 = 'jack'
user2 = 'jill'
access = 0
for i in range(3):

    username = input('Login:>>')

    if username == user1:
        print('access granted')
        access = 1
        break

    elif username == user2:
        print('welcome to the system')
        access = 1
        break

if not access:
    print('access denied')
```

Comment: thanks for that and to all people who answered stack overflow works

Comment: `else` should be unindented.

Comment: No. I tried it and it works.

Comment: It "works," but it gives the "access denied" message after each attempt instead of after all three attempts have been used.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I was suggesting you use the `else` clause of the `for` loop instead of a flag.  :-)